# Noun + Gerund vs Gerund + Noun

Tags: meaning, nouns, abbreviations, gerunds

I try to shorten the expression: "period [of smth] when [the device] moves / stands" to use it as a parameter name, and have come up with these two options:

1. 'Period moving' / 'Period standing'
2. 'Moving period' / 'Standing period'

It feels to me that 'Moving period' rather means 'moving the period' or 'movable period' than 'period in motion'. Is it correct? Which option fits better?

Comment: As you note, you're removing structural words. Every time you do that, you increase ambiguity by destroying the structures that disambiguate them. It's your choice how much you value unambiguous names and how much you value short names. You can have some of each or all of either, but not all of both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use gerund or present participle before noun. And depending on which of the two you use, their meanings can be completely different.

For example)

A sleeping pill: a pill you use to get sleep. 
A sleeping baby: a baby who is sleeping.

A flying field: an aifield.
A flying bird: a bird which is flying.

A smoking room: a room for smoking cigarettes.
A smoking dish: a dish from which smoke is coming out.

As you can notice, if a gerund is used before noun, it specifies purposes of the following nouns. A pill for sleeping, a field for flying, and a room for smoking.

Considering the general usage of travelling (travel) time which means time required for travelling (travel), and travelling (travel) period which means period when you can travel or you want to travel,  I think moving period and standing period are the ones you are looking for.

You can get more examples of compound words with gerund and noun by visiting the below link.

[link](http://www.english-for-students.com/Compound-Words-with-Gerund-and-Noun.html)

Hope it helps.